# Using collection helpers in meteor tabular

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, datatables

I'm displaying table data using Meteor [aldeed:tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular)

The tabular initialization code is simple:

```
this.TabularTables.Customers = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "Clients",
    collection: this.Customers,
    columns: [
        {data: "lastName", title: "Name"},
        {data: "myMessage()", title: "Message"}
    ],
});
```

First field, lastName works perfectly, but adding second field myMessage() causes the problem

I installed dburles:collection-helpers extension and add helper in common code section:

```
this.Customers = new Mongo.Collection("customers");
this.Customers.helpers({
    myMessage: function () {
        return "Hi!";
    }
});
```

But still getting error on the client side:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: a[i[j]] is not a function
at c (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
at jquery.dataTables.min.js:17
```

What might be the problem with my helper function and where should I declare it?

Comment: {data: "myMessage()", title: "Message"} - you have put the function call myMessage() in inverted commas, which presumably makes it into a simple string instead of a function call

Comment: no, it should not be function call - it just a string what will be parsed by tabular package and if it contains brackets - it will be converted to function call

Comment: Yeah, you're right, seen it in the docs. I'm thinking of trying this package, but unfortunately it's another nice-looking package that seems it's not being actively maintained...

Comment: An obvious question, i know, did you install the dburles collection-helper package?

Comment: Sure, I did otherwise I would catch error earlier in helper definition  as this.Customers.helper function is added by collection-helper package

Answer (score 2):

I've done more or less exactly what you have done and it works nicely.

```
Countries = new Mongo.Collection('countries');

TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Countries = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "CountriesList",
    collection: Countries,
    columns: [
        {data: 'italian_name', title: 'Italian name'},
        {data: 'catalogueName',title: 'Catalogue name'},
        {data: "myFunction()", title: 'Wot'}
    ]
});

Countries.helpers({
    myFunction: function () {
        return "Hi!";
    }
});
```

The only real difference I can see is this line:

```
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);
```

Comment: Yeah, that simple example works for me too, but my table - doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem: TabulatTables use collection transformer dburles:collection-helpers to call necessary function, but it confilcts with perak:joins that defines his own helpers

Comment: I simply disabled perak:joins. I think it's better to make joins in code